# Is this Vigor cantrip balanced?

Tags: homebrew-review, pathfinder-2e, cantrips, healing, temporary-hit-points

One of the people I play with wants to play a *very* dedicated healer. The class is of course a Cleric with Healing Font, most free slots are also filled with Heal, the rest are buffs and utility.

He wants also a cantrip that heals. I told him actually regaining HP would upset the balance of out-of-combat healing, but temporary HP might be fine.

I am a bit worried it might be too many tHP, on 3rd level this cantrip gives as much as Endure from a 1st level slot. Also, does it need a cool down period (like Guidance)?

### Vigor

**Traditions** divine
**Cast** 2 somatic, verbal
**Range** 30 feet; **Targets** 1 creature
**Duration** 1 minute

---

You invigorate the target’s body and urge it to press on. You grant the target  temporary Hit Points equal to your spellcasting ability modifier.

---

**Heightened (+1)** Increase the temporary Hit Points by 1.

Comment: Have you considered just having your player take the Bard dedication and grab [Hymn of Healing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=728)? Seems like that'll do exactly what you want.

Comment: @ESCE, thematically great, but it takes 2 class feats and is not available before level 4. I will mention it to him, but I cannot really recommend it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have the effect of the spell **active only on a creature at the time**. This way the effect can't be spammed, and the cleric must put real thought into whom to give to.

**Since it's two actions** I would implement some roll of a dice, e.g. 1d4 + spellcasting ability modifier at second level and after. I don't find this addendum so OP and it gives a nice feeling, and uncertainty, to the cleric that casts the spell, IMHO.

Out of combat, the cleric could use it to someone as they are doing something dangerous, but I wouldn't think much of it. Not all hazards deal only damage - ;) - and even if they do, the damage is still enough to harm the character. At third level, vigor would give (with max ability modifier) in average, 8 temporary hit points, with a max of 12; [Fireball Rune](https://2e.aonprd.com/Hazards.aspx?ID=7), 3rd-level hazard, deals 30 damage on average, with a max of 60. Vigor is useful, as it should be, for the cleric's contentment, but it doesn't break the game, again, IMHO.

In the end, this would be my output:

### Vigor

**Traditions** divine
**Cast** 2 somatic, verbal
**Range** 30 feet; Targets 1 creature
**Duration** 1 minute

You invigorate the target’s body and urge it to press on. You grant the target temporary Hit Points equal to your spellcasting ability modifier. If you cast this spell again on a second creature, the vigor spell on the first creature ends. If you cast this spell again on the same creature, the previous lasting temporary Hit Points are replaced.

**Heightened (+1)** Increase the temporary Hit Points by 1d4.

---

---

Addendum: I thought about comparing the 3rd-level hazard with the 2nd-level Vigor, as spells scale differently. In doubt, I chose the 3rd-level Vigor, since it's the better possibility to consider for the cleric.

Answer (score 8):

## The amount is too little

Endure is [widely regarded](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTM1aBK2R2JYUHGie7C93kbODLO6nh79no8QQj4tgGLfXIqNYOaFQAKjXKTCL0RKO8MscnBRPbEPLjZ/pub) as a [weak spell](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TOd9-spwBjst13NRHEr1fl8AyrK3trsofTHzfEJy30E/mobilebasic), so being stronger than it is not necessarily overpowered.
On the other hand, even strong slotted spells will sooner or later be overtaken by cantrips:

- Electric Arc on level 3 is arguably stronger than Burning Hands in a 1st level slot
- Haunting Hymn on level 5 is *strictly* stronger than Burning Hands in a 1st level slot (unless the enemy has weaknesses to fire)

[Renewed Vigor](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=153) is a Barbarian class feat, providing Con + half you level of tHP for 1 action, which is just a bit less than this cantrip (because your Con is usually less than the spellcasting ability modifier of a full caster).
Based on Scorching Ray, Magic Missile and Rip the Spirit, the effect should be about doubled when you go from 1 action to 2.
**Increase the scaling to 2/level.**

## The duration is too long

If you keep it one minute, the Cleric will just use it on everyone before entering any rooms. *That* is overpowered, and slows the game. Change it to **1 round**.

## The rest is fine

The **range** is the usual 30 feet, like most cantrips. The caster can't be too far back, but does not have to wade into melee either.

The **casting time** is 2 actions, so it is the *main* part of your turn. It is one reason why this cantrip is not better than Endure. You can cast for example Heroism in the same round as that, but not after this cantrip.

The lack of **cool down** is not a problem, just like a good Champion can use his reaction on the same target. Unlike the Champion, you need to *guess* who will be damaged. Unlike Guidance, it is not the target's decision to use the benefit.

Comment: +1 for the duration change. It's also just annoying to track. However, I couldn't see this spell being used **in** combat either way, aside from someone who was devoted enough to healing that they would be fine playing sub-optimally. I might also reduce this to 1 action; I worry it won't see much use otherwise, although it definitely becomes more powerful at one action.

Comment: @ESCE, I want to keep the casting time. What if I reduce the duration, and increase the scaling to 2 temporary HP per level. Isn't that too strong?

Comment: @ESCE: Even at 1 round duration, you could spam it while walking along, in case the person ahead of you walks into a trap.  Or on someone before opening a door.  (Especially if you worry the door might be trapped, or there might be enemies waiting to ambush.)  I'm not familiar with Pathfinder's action economy, but it makes sense that it wouldn't be useful in most combats.  So that leaves balancing it for cases where the caster isn't doing anything else, but someone else is doing something potentially dangerous.

Comment: In PF2e, you can maintain casting a Cantrip while walking around, but if you do so for 10+ minutes you become Fatigued (and at the expense of other Exploration Activities like Searching for traps/secrets). So it is a fairly reasonable strategy to maintain this for a while for just such an issue. In fact, making it one round makes it that much more reasonable instead of allowing people to cast it on the entire party 1/minute as an Exploration

Comment: I can't find the rule about becoming fatigued anymore, I think they might have changed it to a nebulous "you wouldn't do this too much because it can cause Fatigue"

Comment: @Ifusaso I think that might be a holdover from the playtest - these days I think it's just replaced with moving half speed (e.g. see the Detect Magic exploration activity: https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=513). Regardless, at a 1 round duration, I don't really think that's a problem even at full speed - someone will start the combat with some extra temp HP. It'll be one person. Not a super big deal.

Comment: @SpearCarrier.no2 if you really want to keep the casting time, then Lordebasta's answer seems reasonable. I wouldn't expect to see it used in combat, though.

Answer (score 8):

### This cantrip is strong, but that's not the real issue

As it is, it kinda works like a [Redeemer's reaction](https://2e.aonprd.com/Causes.aspx?ID=2), blocking the next few damages one of your friends would take. You have the following advantages:

- the reach is way better: the Redeemer has to be at max 15ft of both the foe and the ally, while you are more free.
- the duration is also better: the Redeemer's reaction is lost if their ally is not hurt during the following round, while your 1 minute duration lets it stick for the rest of the fight
- you block one more damage at lvl 1
- you can target yourself

While the Redeemer's reaction has for it:

- it is a reaction, which is usually worth less than 2 actions
- it scales with levels
- it also gives a status penalty (or blocks all damages)

In my opinion all that considered makes both option comparably strong on lvl1 (if the issue of the second part doesn't come up). The cantrip becomes less and less good as level increases but that's normal for a cantrip.

The way they work means the two of them can stack, which means you won't make your pally friend feel sad by stealing their job.

### The issue is non-combat situations

The real issue is that, since this spell has a duration of 1 minute, you could theoretically casts it on each of your friends and keep it running at every moment. This makes it way more powerful than it should be AND slows down the game.

This problem can be avoided if you make it so that it can't be cast outside of combat. Either:

- reduce the duration to one round
- impose a cool down period like Guidance (what I would recommend)
- make the temp hp disappear if you cast the spell on someone else (like Light)

Comment: I think this is a good analysis with good solutions, but while at early levels the abilities are comparable, the resistance to _all_ damage will frequently block more than the number in total damage when multi-type attacks become more common. I do agree with your assessment of the real issue.